# creating video from selected images using FFMPEG through command Line Android

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg

i am trying to make a video from selected images from command line using ffmpeg in android

using [this](https://github.com/guardianproject/SSCVideoProto) project as my source i m trying to make video

this is the command i m trying to create video

```
   String[] ffmpegCommand = {ffmpegBin,
            "-y",
            "-qscale",
            "1",
            "-r", "" + frameRate,
            "-i", image1.getAbsolutePath(),
            "-t", "" + (((4) * 30) + 4), //"-s",heightwidth,
            "-i", image2.getAbsolutePath(),
            "-t", "" + (((4) * 30) + 4), //"-s",heightwidth,
            "-i", image3.getAbsolutePath(),
            "-t", "" + (((4) * 30) + 4), //"-s",heightwidth,
            "-i", image4.getAbsolutePath(),
            "-t", "" + (((4) * 30) + 4), //"-s",heightwidth,
            "-vcodec",
            "libx264",
            "-s",
            "640x480",
            outputFile.getAbsolutePath()};
```

but the video created shows only 1st image and video is created of less than a second

what is the problem in this statement ? and why only 1 image is shown in video?

sorry about my bad english

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here i am creating video of 12 seconds from 4 images each of 3 seconds with fade in fade out effects.

Run below command and make sure that all the images having same height width.

```
String strCommand = "ffmpeg -loop 1 -t 3 -i " + /sdcard/videokit/1.jpg + " -loop 1 -t 3 -i " + /sdcard/videokit/2.jpg + " -loop 1 -t 3 -i " + /sdcard/videokit/3.jpg + " -loop 1 -t 3 -i " + /sdcard/videokit/4.jpg + " -filter_complex [0:v]trim=duration=3,fade=t=out:st=2.5:d=0.5[v0];[1:v]trim=duration=3,fade=t=in:st=0:d=0.5,fade=t=out:st=2.5:d=0.5[v1];[2:v]trim=duration=3,fade=t=in:st=0:d=0.5,fade=t=out:st=2.5:d=0.5[v2];[3:v]trim=duration=3,fade=t=in:st=0:d=0.5,fade=t=out:st=2.5:d=0.5[v3];[v0][v1][v2][v3]concat=n=4:v=1:a=0,format=yuv420p[v] -map [v] -preset ultrafast " + /sdcard/videolit/output.mp4;
```

Comment: like cross fade , fade in, fade out, 

are there any more transitions in ffmpeg that i can use to create animated video

i m stuck on creating video with transition between images for months

thanks in advance

Comment: This works perfectly! The problem is that takes a lot of time (more than a minute!) Do you know something apart from the ultrafast option?

Comment: getting an error "Unable to find a suitable output format for 'ffmpeg'", and if i remove ffmpeg it stuck on onProgress() method

Comment: How to create GIF instead of video?

Answer (score 2):

This is the ffmpeg command that you should adapt into your string array:

```
ffmpeg -framerate 25 -t 124 -loop 1 -i image1
       -framerate 25 -t 124 -loop 1 -i image2
       -framerate 25 -t 124 -loop 1 -i image3
       -framerate 25 -t 124 -loop 1 -i image4
       -filter_complex "[0][1][2][3]concat=n=4"
       -c:v libx264 -s 640x480 outputfile
```

Rule is that input options (framerate, t..etc)  go *before* the input entry.

The concat filter joins the image streams together. If they are different sizes, you should resize to make them the same.

Comment: thank you for replying 

but it gives me error on '-filter_complex ' i.e. "un recognized option 'filter-complex'

Comment: It's an underscore, not a hyphen - `filter_complex`

Comment: '-filter_complex' after using this is still gives me the same error

Comment: ffmpeg version N-32369-gc0323b9, Copyright (c) 2000-2011 the FFmpeg developers

this is the version of ffmpeg placed in raw folder.
may be it is because of the this version
. how can i download the latest version of the ffmpeg please guide me

Comment: That's a very old version. Get it from https://ffmpeg.org/download.html

Comment: now i m confused.. in the project i used as base i.e. 

https://github.com/guardianproject/SSCVideoProto

there is only 1 file in raw folder

but when i download new version of ffmeg there are a lot of project files

Which one should i pick and which one should i use?


sorry for asking again and again

this is my project requirement and they specifically told me to use ffmeg and without ndk using the above link as source

Comment: You should get a static build, which is only one file.

Comment: i tried as you suggessted but all of the files i downloaded gives main these error i.e. 
1) ffmpeg[1]: syntax error:
2) ffmpeg[1]: ( missing 

now again i dont know how to solve this issue