# How to merge list of Bitmaps and run it on VideoView?

Tags: android, android-videoview, android-bitmap

I am getting image frames from the server and saving them locally as a list of `Bitmap`s. I want to merge those `Bitmap`s into a video and run it on the `VideoView`.
Also is it possible to display/run the video simultaneously with the incoming stream of frames (can I append the `Bitmap` to the running video)?

Comment: You can do this using FFMPEG see this thread here. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38843358/creating-video-from-selected-images-using-ffmpeg-through-command-line-android

Comment: More over you may look at this as well https://github.com/tanersener/mobile-ffmpeg